# How to solve error "Cannot find module 'dns' or its corresponding type declarations." in ReactTS

Tags: typescript, dns, vite, react-tsx

Im new to Typescript and im getting this error in vite.config.ts file [inside vite.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQbK.png), when im trying to set the default result order to verbatim using dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim').

Im new to both vite and Typescript so any help or suggestions would be appreciated